# Can't render smoke on GPU in 2.77 testbuild 1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, gpu

It says smoke/fire in cycles has CUDA support now, but I can't seem to get it to work, even on the experimental feature set. Running a GTX 770, 4GB.

Comment: I just made a test rendering smoke on GPU (GTX 780) and it does work on my system.  Since this is still a testbuild I would wait for the official release.

Comment: Works for me on GTX 460

Comment: @cegaton Or better yet - [report it](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug) before the release so it can get fixed. That is what the testbuilds and rc releases are for.